# Nginx geoipblocking & allowing LAN IPs

Tags: nginx, local-area-network, ip-blocking, whitelist, geoip

I'd like to block IPs with geoip except whitelisted countries AND the local area network. 
The first part works flawless, the second one not.
Somwehere searching the internet I found the codes LH (local host) and LN (local network), but they are both not working.

I'm using the standard howto code for the blocking.

The relevant http {} part in nginx.conf:

```
geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
   map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {
    default no;                              
    US yes;
   }
```

The relevant server {} part in sites-available/default:

```
block countries
      if ($allowed_country = no) {
        return 444;
      }
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Update:

$geoip_country_code variable returns "-" on LAN IP access, but adding "- yes;" to the geoip_county block doesn't work either.

Comment: You could just log what's in `$geoip_country_code` variable when you access nginx from local network. Then just add this value to `map` directive.

Comment: If you used the access logs, then the "-" value you mentioned is used to indicate missing data (see [NCSA Common log format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format)).

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution - no idea if it's 'clean'. Just overwrite the $allowed_country variable if a lan IP condition was matched before.

> geo $lan-ip {
>          default no;
>          192.168.1.0/24   yes;
>          }

and this block before the  "#block countries" part

> if ($lan-ip = yes) {
>          set $allowed_country yes;
>          }

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following:

```
map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {
    default no;
    '' yes;
    US yes;
}
```

Although it won't just apply to LAN/private network IP addresses, but to all addresses that aren't handled by your GeoIP database.